# An Unfamiliar Day in the Life

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

Let me tell you about the day in my life that everything changed.  Maybe it will sound something like your life.  Maybe only bits and pieces will seem familiar.

> I got up early this morning, but that isn’t out of the ordinary- the men in my commune usually wake everybody up at the crack of dawn.  As the sun was rising, the excitement was rising as well.  We knew that daylight would bring visitors, as well as interesting sights, sounds, and smells.  Some of the ladies took time to dress up their choicest body parts, feeling that these might garner them attention.  Others did their best to look young and vital, capable of starting a family and growing it for many years.
>
> While they strutted their stuff, I sat alone on the ground.  I guess that’s just where I am comfortable, with the simple pleasures.  I closed my eyes to listen to the day, when all of the sudden, I was embraced and lifted from my place.  Immediately, I knew.  I had been chosen.  I was going to be taken away to live in a new place, with this kind old man.  He looked like he had spent many a day in the sun, but this seemed to have kept him warm on the inside.  Sure, there were stories of other freedom-seeking ladies, leaving the commune only to be cooped up day and night, just trying to scratch out a livelihood.  These did not matter to me.  The man seemed nice, and I was ready to start the sunny side of my life.
>
> Travelling with the man, sometimes in his arms, sometimes at his heels, we stopped at two other communes, where he brought two more additions into his “family”.  One was much bigger than me, and I didn’t really trust him.  He seemed to have eyes for me, but there was something sinister there as well.  He would slink around and make me feel uncomfortable.  The third addition became my enemy as well, and my glaring eyes said as much.  This was because the third addition could not walk, and thus had to be carried.  Angry and uneasy, I now stuck very close to my new patron and did my best to stay in his eyesight.
>
> This was effective and it relaxed me, but it did not last.  As we neared the man’s home, he became nervous and somewhat puzzled.  Something seemed to be stopping us from going any further.  It became apparent that he had not coordinated his travel plans very well, but obviously wanted to ensure safe passage to us all.  He didn’t want to split up this “family” that just barely formed, and even more did not want us to fall in harm’s way.
>
> I sat in the dirt as the man began sketching out diagrams in it,    counting to himself, and pointing at the three of us and himself in    various orders.  I began to let myself listen to the day again and    must have drifted into a light sleep.  I remember him hugging me    three more times or so, but wasn’t fully awake again until we had    reached his home.  He seemed pleased, relieved, and remarked about    how “it was all so easy.”  He must have been referring to the kind of    life we’ll get to lead, the easy life.

**Questions**

- Who is narrating this day?
- Who makes up the "family" the narrator joins?
- What really happened on this day? *(remember the narrator missed some things while asleep)*

Comment: Did you write this up yourself? What country are you from?

Comment: @Octopus Yeah, I wrote it. Like I said in my comment to Irishpanda, I just thought it would be fun to see this puzzle from a new perspective. And I'm American. Does the writing indicate something other than that? I mean I *did* go to a liberal arts school, so...yeah...

Comment: You spelled travelling with two Ls. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The narrator is:

> The chicken from the fox, chicken, and bag of corn puzzle (scratching out a living, cooped up)

the family is:

> The farmer, the chicken, the fox (slinking around, makes the chicken uneasy), the bag of corn (had to be carried)

What happened?

> Why, the farmer collected all the "family members" and on the way home happened on the river that he had to cross safely without any of the family eating one of the others. The chicken had vague recollections of the times she had been carried across.

Comment: Nice, nice, and nice!  I hope it wasn't too easy.  It was a bit of a stretch for me to call it *Unfamiliar*, but I thought that seeing this classic puzzle from another perspective could be fun.

Comment: There have been a few lately that have taken the same approach using song lyrics, and it works here as well. I find it rather fun.